# Are global computed properties thread safe?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, thread-safety

Reading about thread safety in this [thread](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/229436), a Swift engineer states:

> Global and static properties are already dispatch_once'd.

I understand that global computed properties are dispatch_once'd but I was wondering if this refers to global computed properties too.

Answer (score 3):

A computed property is evaluated on demand and therefore is not inherently thread safe. Every time you invoke a computed property's getter, that function is going to run on the invoking thread.